# Why isn't my Scrollmagic/Greenstock animation working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, scrollmagic

i just started working with scrollmagic, but i can't seem to get it functioning properly. I followed a simple tutorial to do a few animations on different sections. I'm not sure if didn't import the classes, right, but i'm stuck. Help would be greatly appreciated and i've attached my js, html, and css file.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ScrollMagic #1 Setup</title>
     <script>
      window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"><\/script>')
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/greensock/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/uncompressed/plugins/animation.gsap.min.js">    </script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <script src="js/uncompressed/ScrollMagic.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/plugins/debug.addIndicators.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<main class="full-screen" role="main">
  <section class="full-screen blue">
    <div>
      <h1>Basic Tweening</h1>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="scale-trigger" class="full-screen orange">
    <div id="scale-animation">
      <p>This element will scale down using the scale value of the CSS transform property.</p>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="bg-trigger" class="full-screen red">
    <div id="bg-animation">
      <p>This element will have the background color change</p>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="yoyo-trigger" class="full-screen blue">
    <div>
      <p id="yoyo-animation">Section Four yoyo Text!</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>

</body>
</html>
```

JS FILE

```
 (function($) {
   // Scale Animation Setup
// .to('@target', @length, {@object})
var scale_tween = TweenMax.to('#scale-animation', 1, {
  transform: 'scale(.75)',
  ease: Linear.easeNone
});

// BG Animation Setup
// .to('@target', @length, {@object})
var bg_tween = TweenMax.to('#bg-trigger', 1, {
  backgroundColor: '#FFA500',
  ease: Linear.easeNone
});

// YoYo Animation Setup
// .to(@target, @length, @object)
var yoyo_tween = TweenMax.to('#yoyo-animation', 1, {
  transform: 'scale(2)',
  ease: Cubic.easeOut,
  repeat: -1, // this negative value repeats the animation
  yoyo: true // make it bounce…yo!
});


// init ScrollMagic Controller
var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();


// Scale Scene
var scale_scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
  triggerElement: '#scale-trigger'
})
.setTween(scale_tween);

// Background Scene
var bg_scene = new  ScrollMagic.Scene({
  triggerElement: '#bg-trigger'
})
.setTween(bg_tween);

// YoYo Scene
var yoyo_scene = new  ScrollMagic.Scene({
  triggerElement: '#yoyo-trigger'
})
.setTween(yoyo_tween);

controller.addScene([
  scale_scene,
  bg_scene,
  yoyo_scene
]);

})(jQuery);
```

CSS FILE

```
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%
}

h1,
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  color: #EFEFEF;
}

.full-screen {
  height: 100%; /* makes panels the entire window height */
}

.blue {
    background-color: #3883d8;
}
.red {
    background-color: #cf3535;
}
.orange {
    background-color: #ea6300;
}
```

Comment: Help the help by setting up a jsfiddle and explaining what isn't working. Sometimes that can come about by explaining what is working. "It isn't working" doesn't really help anyone.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the suggestions. The part that isn't working are the actually animations. If you look in the javascriptt section it uses greenstick animations, but they aren't functioning properly. On the scale and backgrund scenes in javascript it should animate the font to scale larger and the backgound scene should change the background. here's the codepen to what i followed: http://codepen.io/grayghostvisuals/pen/wzFnb

Comment: @playermany2 That codepen seems to work just fine, you might have to explain your issue in more details.

Comment: @playermany2 Right, that is not actually your code in that codepen. This is a basic start that might need to be tweaked to reproduce whatever is happening to you: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZbJEQe